# How to fix "Error: Cannot find module '/home/site/wwwroot/index.js" with an app deployed to Azure?

Tags: node.js, azure, github-actions

I'm attempting for the first time to deploy a node.js app to Azure as an Azure App Service, but I'm facing this stubborn error when trying to run the app that I haven't figured out how to troubleshoot. Maybe someone here has some hints on where I'm making the mistake.

To give some background:

- I'm working on a project that has a subset of directories, each of the directories being an app (server, client, ...)
- The main directory is the git directory
- The nodejs app I am working on is built with typescript, and leveraging Apollo Server (which itself leverages express)
- I'm deploying to Azure via GitHub

With that in mind, my project folder structure looks like:

```
| main_folder
  | .github
    | workflows
        workflow.yml
  | server
    | src
    | dist
    .env
    index.ts
    package-lock.json
    package.json
    tsconfig.json    
  | other_apps
  .gitignore
  README.md
```

In `index.ts` I have the code relevant to running the app. The rest of the relevant files look like this:
`tsconfig.json`

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES2022",
        "module": "CommonJS",
        "lib": [
            "ES2022", "DOM"
        ],
        "strict": true,
        "rootDir": ".",
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true
    }
}
```

`package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "ts-node-dev --transpile-only --no-notify --exit-child index.ts",
    "build": "npx tsc",
    "start": "node ."
  },
  // ...
}
```

`workflow.yml`

```yaml
on:
  push:
    branches: ["master"]
  workflow_dispatch:

env:
  AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME: my-app-name 
  AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH: "." # set this to the path to your web app project, defaults to the repository root
  NODE_VERSION: "16.x" # set this to the node version to use

permissions:
  contents: read

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: ./server
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Set up Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: ${{ env.NODE_VERSION }}
          cache: "npm"
          cache-dependency-path: ./server/package-lock.json

      - name: npm install, build, and test
        run: |
          npm install
          npm run build --if-present
          npm run test --if-present

      - name: Zip artifact for deployment
        run: zip -r release.zip ./* .env

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: node-app
          path: ./server/release.zip

  deploy:
    permissions:
      contents: none
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: "Development"
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: node-app

      - name: unzip artifact for deployment
        run: unzip release.zip

      - name: "Deploy to Azure WebApp"
        id: my_app_id
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_NAME }}
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZURE_WEBAPP_PUBLISH_PROFILE }}
          package: ${{ env.AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}
```

This app works perfectly fine in local (running `npm run dev`). When I push to `master` in GitHub, both the build & deployment jobs **work correctly**. However, when I go to Azure Portal and check on the app, I see these two things:

When I open the url for the app, the page shows:
[image: App failing to access]

When I check the diagnostics of the app in Azure, it tells me:
[image: Azure diagnostics of the app]

The error being `Error: Cannot find module '/home/site/wwwroot/index.js'`. While setting up the configurations for automatic build & deployment in GitHub I faced several issues with my project structure, as my git repository doesn't actually contain any app (package.json), but they are instead in nested folders. However, I don't think this error stems from that set up, but from somewhere else.

Can somebody hint me on what I'm doing wrong here? I'll repeat that this is my first attempt at publishing a nodejs app to Azure, and even though I think I followed the docs correctly, there are chances I messed up in an obvious step. I would appreciate having anybody pointing it out if that's the case!

I'll be happy to add any more information to the description that might be relevant to the issue.

Comment: In the Zip artifact for deployment step you should include only the content of your dist folder. There is no need to deploy your entire working folder. Also, instead of using .env on production you should use Web app Configuration

Comment: If you are studying Azure App Service, try to use its Docker image deployment option. In that way you can test out the image locally and expect Azure to run it the same way.

Comment: If it's SPA, you could try using pm2. 

Update the Startup Command to: pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot/dist --no-daemon --spa

https://azureossd.github.io/2022/02/07/React-Deployment-on-App-Service-Linux/index.html

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem (Error: Cannot find module '/home/site/wwwroot/index.js').

When I checked the source code, I could't find index.js, but found server.js.

My solution:

1. Change the server.js to index.js,
2. then check the package.json  "main": "index.js",

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to reproduce this by creating a sample node.js webapp and pushed the code to github.

Created an Azure App service with github actions CI/CD pipelines and deployed successfully.

Make sure you have the below Project Structure:

[image]

Created a secret in GitHub by using the publish profile of azure app service from portal as shown in below image:

[image]

After configuring the above steps, Push the code from local repo to git repo then it will trigger the github pipelines and code will be deployed to azure app service as shown in below screenshot:

[image]

You can go to the azure portal and check the deployement as successful as shown below:

[image]

***Output screen after clicking on the Azure app service url:***
[image]

Comment: My app was deployed successfully. However, I am still facing the same error as the OP.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same situation.

I hope you have solved this issues by now. However if not, I reckon the problem was thatthe app was looking at `./server/index.ts` after deployment, instead of its Javascript version.

Here is my solution, you have already compiled the files, so in `package.json`, change to the start script to

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "node dist/index.js" 
  }
```

Now deploy again, it should show you the correct page.